# How to select first a element of li with CSS?

Tags: css, nested-lists, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the first anchor tag of a nested li menu tree:

```
<div class="footermenu">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="expanded first">
        <a href="link.html">First menupoint</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first"><a href="#">First submenupoint</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second submenupoint</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Third submenupoint</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#">Fourth submenupoint</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded last">
        <a href="link.html">Second menupoint</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first"><a href="#">First submenupoint</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second submenupoint</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Third submenupoint</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#">Fourth submenupoint</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to select only the first anchor tag of the main menupoints.

My css is:

```
div.footermenu li.expanded a:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;    
}
```

The problem is that this CSS still selects the submenupoints and I don't know why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use `div.footermenu li.expanded > a:first-child`

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/eRTV6/

```
div.footermenu li.expanded > a:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;    
}
```

Your original selector will select all anchor elements which are first-children of `li.expanded`, by adding a direct descendant selector, `>`, you specify that you only want to select the first, direct descendant of `li.expanded` which are anchors.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style TYPE="text/css">
        div.footermenu li.expanded>a{
            font-weight: bold;
            background: Red;    
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="footermenu">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="expanded first">
        <a href="link.html">First menupoint</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first"><a href="#">First submenupoint</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second submenupoint</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Third submenupoint</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#">Fourth submenupoint</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded last">
        <a href="link.html">Second menupoint</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first"><a href="#">First submenupoint</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second submenupoint</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Third submenupoint</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#">Fourth submenupoint</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will make all the <a> tags between the <li> and the sub <ul> bold. I think he only wants to make the first one bold.

Comment: There IS only one tag in each case... 100% of 1 is, erm, 1.

Comment: But he said that he specifically only wants to target the first one of those. It might only have one link now, what if that's an example?

Comment: +1 for spotting unclosed Div... As for the rest, look how he builds the menus. There will only ever be 1 item on an expanded menu...